# php doesn't pass through any of the if statement and goes directly to the else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

can someone tell me please whats wrong with this, i think i got everything right but my return value pops out everything which is my command for the last else command the if statements doesn't seem to work...

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","d_database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$images = array();
if(isset($_GET['mydata']) )
    $mydata = $_GET['mydata'];
if(isset($_GET['category']) )
    $category = $_GET['category'];

if($category == 'Users'){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, dish_name, dish_image, user_username FROM recipes WHERE user_username = '$mydata'");
}else if ($category == 'Recipes'){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, dish_name, dish_image, user_username FROM recipes WHERE dish_name =  '$mydata'");
}else if ($category == 'Ingredients'){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, dish_name, dish_image, user_username FROM recipes WHERE user_username =  '$mydata'");
}else{
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, dish_name, dish_image, user_username FROM recipes");
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $images[] = $row;
}

echo "{images:".json_encode($images)."}";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about basic debugging.

Comment: `var_dump( $category );`

Comment: i dont even know what thats var_dump

Comment: Add `}` after `echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();`

Comment: In your comment below you said you are passing the following values in your query string: http://localhost/Login/main.php?mydata=%27george%27&category=%27Users%27&quot The %27 is an encoded single quote. You should remove them as they are not needed and your PHP is not checking for them.

Comment: oh didn't see that doing... testing :3

Comment: Try to print the `$result`

Comment: i'm passing this "http://localhost/Login/main.php?mydata=%27george%27&category=%27Users%27"

Comment: Might be sensible to forgo `isset` constructs until you know what's happening. Your code is also generating invalid JSON in the last line.

Comment: it has an output but it doesn't seem to pass the Users, Ingredients, or Recipes if statement it keeps going to the last else statement

Comment: As you told us, in the comment... you are trying to pass `http://localhost/Login/main.php?mydata=%27george%27&category=%27Users%27%22` - remove quotes from URL

Comment: @george http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: i did :3 i just put quotes in it hoping it wont turn to a link

Answer (score -1):

i was using a POST method im my forms
so thats why it was wrong... :(((

```
if(isset($_POST['mydata']) )
    $mydata = $_POST['mydata'];
if(isset($_POST['category']) )
    $category = $_POST['category'];
```

fix my problem